# Two ReactJs SPAs on IIS in a folder and a subfolder

Tags: reactjs, iis, url-rewriting

I have a quite complicated configuration for IIS:

I have two different single-page applications, made with ReactJS+Redux, to put on the same domain, but one of them should be placed in a subfolder.

Example:

https://www.example.org/ -> It loads the first SPA which has several routes.
https://www.example.org/UniquePathToSecondApp/ -> It loads the second SPA, which has also its own routes.

The problem I can't solve is that the first app, running on the root, grabs all the request paths trying to match it with the routes definition, therefore also the path "UniquePathToSecondApp" is processed by the first.

How can I set IIS to redirect all the requests for the path starting with "https://www.example.org/UniquePathToSecondApp/" to the second SPA and keep this URL in the browser address bar?

*** UPDATE: Added the web.config ***

This is the current web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Static Assets" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="([\S]+[.](html|htm|svg|js|css|png|gif|jpg|jpeg))" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="block" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="^api" />
           <action type="None" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="ReactRouter Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In IIS I have the following configuration

[image]

Comment: Open up `web.config` of the first web app, and add a new rewrite rule to do nothing for  all requests of the second.

Comment: Please provide us with your URL rewrite rule settings in web.config.

Comment: @LexLi It works if I add a stop processing rule for the subfolder, but then, the issue is that I get a 404 if I write the URL of the second website directly in the browser, example: https://www.example.org/UniquePathToSecondApp/some-internal-route, because it's not catched by the rewrite for /index.html

Answer (score 0):

Do the following rules work for you?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Rule to handle requests for the second SPA in the subfolder -->
        <rule name="SecondApp" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^UniquePathToSecondApp/(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/UniquePathToSecondApp/index.html" />
        </rule>

        <!-- Rule to handle requests for the first SPA at the root -->
        <rule name="FirstApp" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The second rule will only be executed when the URL does not start with "UniquePathToSecondApp/".